# TypeError: _this.setState is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm fairly new to react native and have been working on a new app. When I try to get user input from two text fields using this.setState I get given the error "not a function" which is extremely confusing because this was working before...?

If someone could shed some light I'd be very grateful!

````
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox'; 
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';

function SignIn({ navigation }){

  this.state = {

    username : "",
    password : ""

  };

    return (
      <View style={styles.body}>
      <Text style={styles.trybetext}> trybe </Text>
      <Text style={styles.nyoftext}>Not Your Ordinary Family</Text>
      <TextInput
          style={styles.username}
          label="username"
          placeholder="Email or Username"
          onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({username: value})}/>
      <TextInput 
          style={styles.password}
          title="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({password: value})}/>
      <CheckBox
      value={false}
      disabled={false}
      style={styles.checkbox}
      />
      <Text style={styles.rememberme}>Remember Me</Text>
      <Text style={styles.forgetpassword}> Forget Your Password? </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginbutton} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Confirmation')}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log In</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{"username ===> "+this.state.username}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginbuttongoogle}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonTextgoogle}>Sign In with Google</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Image 
        style={styles.googleIcon}
        source = {require('../android/app/src/img/googleIcon.png')}/>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginbuttonfacebook}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In with Facebook</Text>
      <Image 
        style={styles.facebookIcon}
        source = {require('../android/app/src/img/facebookIcon.png')}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginbuttonapple}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In with Apple</Text>
      <Image 
        style={styles.appleIcon}
        source = {require('../android/app/src/img/appleIcon.png')}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.text} onPress={() => alert(username)}>Do not have an account? Create Account</Text>
    </View>
    )
  }```
````

Comment: you can't use this.state in function components, use a class based components. Please go through React docs regarding state management

Comment: Adding @VaibhavVishal, for functional component, you can use useState hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: Ahh that works now! I had no idea, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right way of using state in a functional component. You need to use `useState` hook to maintain your state

for example

```
function SignIn({ navigation }) {
  const [username, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  // .... your rest of the code
}
```

and you can set the state as follows

```
<TextInput
 style={styles.username}
 label="username"
 placeholder="Email or Username"
 value={username}               // ===> the state value
 onChangeText={(value) => setUserName(value)}  // ====> changing value of username
/>
```

You can do the same for password field.

Also if you need further guidance please refer to [Official Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 0):

use hooks to define state in functional components.
Below code will help you out.

```js
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox'; 
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import {useState} from 'react';

function SignIn({ navigation }){

  const [state,setState] = useState({
    username : "",
    password : ""
  });

    return (
      <View style={styles.body}>
      <Text style={styles.trybetext}> trybe </Text>
      <Text style={styles.nyoftext}>Not Your Ordinary Family</Text>
      <TextInput
          style={styles.username}
          label="username"
          placeholder="Email or Username"
          onChangeText={(value) => setState({...state,username: value})}/>
      <TextInput 
          style={styles.password}
          title="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={(value) => setState({...state,password: value})}/>
      <CheckBox
      value={false}
      disabled={false}
      style={styles.checkbox}
      />
      <Text style={styles.rememberme}>Remember Me</Text>
      <Text style={styles.forgetpassword}> Forget Your Password? </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginbutton} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Confirmation')}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log In</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{"username ===> "+state.username}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginbuttongoogle}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonTextgoogle}>Sign In with Google</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Image 
        style={styles.googleIcon}
        source = {require('../android/app/src/img/googleIcon.png')}/>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginbuttonfacebook}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In with Facebook</Text>
      <Image 
        style={styles.facebookIcon}
        source = {require('../android/app/src/img/facebookIcon.png')}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginbuttonapple}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In with Apple</Text>
      <Image 
        style={styles.appleIcon}
        source = {require('../android/app/src/img/appleIcon.png')}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.text} onPress={() => alert(state.username)}>Do not have an account? Create Account</Text>
    </View>
    )
  }
```